# How can I call a function from another component while keeping the other component generic in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, components, selector

I am trying get component1 to trigger a function in component2, but component2 needs to stay generic so it can be accessed by any component. Without making it generic, my code looks like this:

component1:

```
@Output() component2function = new EventEmitter<any>();
...
this.component2function.emit({ param1, param2 });
```

component2 selector:

```
<component1 (component2function)="component2function($event)"> </component1>
```

This should trigger `component2function` but now I want to trigger that same function without explicitly using the `component1` selector, so that `component2function` can be triggered by components other than component1. How can I do this?

Comment: why don't you use a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the function into a shared service instead. That way, all you need to do is provide the service via the constructor of each component. Component 1, component 2, and component 3 then can all access this shared function easily.

Service.ts

```
@Injectible({
   providedIn: "root"
})
export class SharedService {
    sharedFunction() {
        let theSolution = ....;

        return theSolution;
    }
}
```

Then in the component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "component1",
  templateUrl: "./component1.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./component1.component.css"]
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.genericFunction();
    }

    genericFunction() {
        this.sharedService.sharedFunction();
    }
}
```

From there you can just call either the service function right from the html or call the component function like above from the html. If you're managing data, the state will be more predictable in a shared service.

Answer (score 1):

So you need some minimum agreement, that the implemented components has this method. You can achieve this by defining an interface, which is inherited by `component1`, ...:

```
interface MyInterface {
    component2function: EventEmitter<any>;
}
```

(Soruce: [How to interface Output() and Input() decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064339/how-to-interface-output-and-input-decorators))

This way, don't have to know exactly what kind of component it is, but can make sure that has this method.

Comment: So the interface is in component2? How do I access it from component1?